# Register spring data repository interface as bean in a java configuration

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a spring data repository interface and I want to register it as a `@Bean` in my java configuration. The reason I want to do this is because the `@Bean` annotation also allows me to have alias (if I provide more than one name for the bean). I cannot do this:

`@Bean(name = {"defaultMyRepo", "myRepo"})
public MyRepository defaultMyRepository() {
    return new MyRepository();
}`

because `MyRepository` is an interface and I cannot instantiate it.

The problem occurs when I try to create a bean in my configuration like this:

```
@Bean(name = { "defaultSearchProductExportWriter", "searchProductExportWriter" })
public RepositoryItemWriter<Serializable> defaultSearchProductExportWriter() {
    final RepositoryItemWriter<Serializable> itemWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setRepository(applicationContext.getBean(ProductSearchRepository.class));
    itemWriter.setMethodName("save");

    return itemWriter;
}
```

Now this will blow with `multiple beans found, expected 1 but found 2`. I also tried passing the required bean as a parameter to the method:

```
@Bean(name = { "defaultSearchProductExportWriter", "searchProductExportWriter" })
public RepositoryItemWriter<Serializable> defaultSearchProductExportWriter(final ProductSearchRepository repository) {
    final RepositoryItemWriter<Serializable> itemWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setRepository(repository);
    itemWriter.setMethodName("save");

    return itemWriter;
}
```

but I got exactly the same exception. It only works if I define the repository interface with a name and alias, and then the overriding bean with different-name and the same alias. This way I can use the `@Qualifier("myAlias")` and it will find the correct overriding repository interface.

This could also be a potential feature request for the spring-data repositories to change the `value` attribute of the `@Repository` annotation to be `String[]` so that we can also register aliases.

Comment: I don't understand the need for multiple names for this repo. Could you explain this?

Comment: why do you need the multiple names? spring will provide exactly one bean for each dao interface, we don't even have to provide a concrete class per dao interface since the dao interface just needs to extends the base spring data interfaces and spring will provide magically the implementation for it. It doesn't make sense the need for multiple bean alias for a dao. You just need to directly autowire the interface regardless of the bean alias.

Comment: Why do you say "It doesn't make sense the need for multiple bean alias for a dao"? I write a platform - I give one interface to my client with some useful methods. Then my clients wants to extend this interface and add some more methods. They register the **new** bean with **alias** and also with **@Primary** so that the platform picks their repository when being autowired. It makes perfect sense to me,

Comment: I still don't get why you need an alias for that. If the extended interface is an @Primary, auto wiring by type should work using both the repository type you define or by the extension type, shouldn't it? What's the reason you autowire by name in the first place?

Comment: @OliverGierke Even though I add `@Primary` to the extended interface it still blows with `expected single matching bean but found 2:`. I tried loadng the interface from the applicationContext like this: `applicationContext.getBean(MyRepository.class)`, or passing it as parameter to the method in my `@Bean` configuration - still the same result.

Comment: Well, why do you access beans from the AC directly? Dependency injecting an instance should work as expected.

Comment: @OliverGierke I added the explanation in the question itself. I'm trying to create another bean in my java configuration and the repository is a dependency. I tried passing it as a parameter to the method, but I got the same exception :(

Answer (score 0):

You could autowire your Repository to the Bean

```
@Bean(name = { "myRepository", "repo" })
public MyRepository myRepository(MyRepository myRepository) {

    return myRepository;
}
```

**Please don't just use this. It's not fully clear to my why it should be necessary at any time to have multiple names for a repository. Read through the comments of the question and use it only if you still think you need multiple names**

A working example can be found here:
https://github.com/Yannic92/stackOverflowExamples/tree/master/SpringBoot/TwoNamesForRepository

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work - when I try it it blows with exception because more than one bean of type `MyRepository` has been found. Indeed I have two beans of this type and I want to register them with different aliases

Comment: I tested this. It should work. Can you provide code?

Comment: I added a link to my github repo where i added a working example with a Repository Bean with 2 names. Is it possible that you try to autowire the Repository somewhere WITHOUT one of these qualifiers? Since you added the bean you need to use the qualifier everytime you inject it somewhere

Comment: Hmm.. your repository worked. However I'm wondering if this is going to register the bean twice.  I'll wait for a few more days and if no better solution comes I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I will think about another solution, too.

Comment: And yes it is going to register the bean twice (One time via Bean and the other via Autodetection for Repositories). To decide which one will be picked you have to use the name as Qualifier

Comment: Yannic Klem answer creates a circular dependency and the IoC will throw a `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException` exception. This doent work

Comment: It does work. I just cloned my repository and ran "mvn spring-boot:run". App started without any issues. I guess you have a specific problem with your code, not with the sample code I provided, right?